# How to add a Floating Action Button, without AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I'm looking to make a new app, using only API 21.

To follow the Material Design, I'm trying to use a FAB, but I cannot find any decent information on how to use the one now included in the Design Library.

So far, I have added the library the the build.gradle file, and added a FAB to my view (code below)

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
```

(This is in a RelativeLayout)

When I launch the app, I get:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

I found one answer on SO that says I need to use an AppCompat theme, but I'd rather just use pure Material/API21 stuff.

How can I use a FAB without AppCompat (support libraries)?

Comment: I think you would really miss out on many timesavers and great API's like CoordinatorLayout, Snackbar, NavigationView, TabLayout... and so on. Which pretty much is all the "pure material stuff". Anyhow, creating your own FloatingActionButton on API21+ is pretty easy. You can take a look at googles implementation in [android-topeka](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/topeka/widget/fab/FloatingActionButton.java).

Answer (score 8):

The FAB is built into the new Design Compat library - which will work on devices as early as API 7.  You will need to include it as a dependency to use it (and shouldn't hesitate to do so).

If you want to avoid using a library (or any external code) you will need to draw the FAB yourself (using a Shape Drawable).

Bottom line, using the Design Compat lib is the preferred method for supporting a FAB, and you should use it.  The Design Compat lib IS the "pure/Material API21 stuff".

There is NOT a FAB implementation implemented for any API other then the one in the Design support lib.  You have to include the lib, or implement the code entirely yourself.

The Design lib has a dependency on AppCompat, so if you are planning on using the native fab, you will also need to include the dependency for AppCompat.

From the [official blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html): "*Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency.*"

Comment: I think there are some crossed wires. I know I need to use the Design Support Library, I'm not on about that. I am saying that it looks as if I have to use the v7 AppCompat stuff, which I don't want to.

Comment: Merged this into answer - bottom line, there is a dependency on AppCompat, so you have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Material Design library has a dependency with AppCompat.
Check the @Booger answer. It reports the official blog.

**How to use a FAB.**

Add the dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Just add the FAB to your design:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal" />
```

Currently there are some bugs.

You have to define `app:borderWidth="0dp"` to display the shadow with API21+.

Also you have to define different margins for API 21+ and older devices.

*res/values/dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="fab_margin_right">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin_bottom">0dp</dimen>
```

*res/values-v21/dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="fab_margin_right">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="fab_margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
```

FAB uses the accent color and you could override with `app:backgroundTint` attribute.

Finally you can set a ClickListener with:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was having the same problem. The solution was quite simple:
you have to define `app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"` 
and you can use a FAB without using Appcompat Themes and Activities. Of course you have to include  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`
but you DO NOT have to use `AppCompatActivity` and those Themes.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_add_palette"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score -1):

There is also several popular libraries on GitHub like:

[FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) which can expand/collapse as menu to reveal multiple actions.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use a 3rd party lib right now - and stick with the "native" implementation included in the Design Lib.  It is important to stick with standards (and the standard "Design Lib Implemented" FAB will get you closest).  I know it may not have as many features (including expandability), but still think it is important to design and implement around emerging standards.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that although you intend to make your app available on API21 only but I encourage you to implement your application using Android Support Library AppCompat-v7 anyway. There are a lot of benefits you will get.

Anyway it is your choice. Just my suggestion. But if you are convinced. Or check out this full tutorial about how to use Android Design Support Library. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Hope this help

Comment: What are the benefits from using the v7 library? Also, it seems I can only use the native FAB using the Design Support Library that HAS to use the AppCompat theme :/